# Complex reThinkDB json to Elasticsearch via logstash

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, nested, logstash, rethinkdb

hope you can help.

**NB: I've updated the logstash.conf**

#### The problem

I'm trying to get a large JSON from reThinkDB into ElasticSearch via LogStash. The logstash.conf configuration is giving me some headaches, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful. Beginner tutorials would be great.

I've traversed the internet, and the ES docs, but it's very hard to wrap my head around still.

The issue is that i get "new_" before all column names, and if i reload the data, I get duplicates.

Additionally, traversing arrays with objects and nested arrays with more objects etc. is giving additional trouble.

#### The seeked solution

What is basically needed is to parse the JSON, dynamically give the column the same name as the object, then add the value to the row. Furthermore collapse the arrays, and give the column the name of the array and the object, ie "arrayname_objectname", and then add the value to the row.

For a 2 level (and further) nested array this should just append, ie. "arrayname_arrayname_objectname", and then the value in the row.

The structure of the JSON may change, but this should be dynamically catered for via the dynamic parsing.

Finally, an id as to not generate duplicates in the ElasticSearch should be given, ie. the doc is from reThinkDB.

**UPDATE**

I get the right structure in ES, but still face the issues with "new_" in front of all columns, and i still get duplicates.
So: How do i designate an ID value for matching (to update as not to get duplicates), and how do i remove the "new_" in the columns?

I have a "id": "b586c597-f043-4857-80ca-2236ca6e9a3d" in one of my records. This is unique for all my records, but how do i designate this properly? If i add "document_id => "%{id}"" in the conf file, only one record is imported, and i get this entry in the logs x 1mio (-1):

```
retrying failed action with response code: 409 {:level=>:warn}
```

.

```
My logstash.conf:

    
input {rethinkdb
   {host => "localhost"
    port => 28015
    auth_key => ""
    watch_dbs => ["customers"]
    watch_tables => ["customers.scv"]
    backfill => true
    }}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "10.3.76.233:9200"
                index => "test"
                action => "create"
                document_id => "%{id}"
        }
}
```

My JSON file from reThinkDB:

```
{
    "name" : "This is the name of the customer.",
    "url" : "Provides the URL (if any) of the customer.",
    "international_dialing_code" : "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the customer.",
    "phone_number" : "Defines the Phone Number of the customer.",
    "street" : "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
    "house_number" : "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer.",
    "po_box" : "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
    "building" : "Provides the building (if any) of the customer.",
    "district" : "Provides the district (if any) of the customer.",
    "city" : "City name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
    "postal_code" : "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer.",
    "iso_subdivision_code" : "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer.",
    "iso_country_code" : "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
    "last_changed_by" : "User identification",
    "last_change_when" : "Timestamp of change",
    "customer_number" : [{
            "cust_number_value" : "Customer code or Customer Number",
            "cust_number_type" : "Type of the customer code. E.g. \"Customer Code\" or \"Customer Alternate Code\" SAP or SCV etc."
        }
    ],
    "external_customer_reference_number" : [{
            "reference_number_type" : "DoDAAC etc. Reference data from another collection.",
            "reference_number_value" : "User provided data"
        }
    ],
    "alternative_trading_name" : [
        "Company alternative name or abberiviation, 1 of many.",
        "Company alternative name or abberiviation, 2 of many."
    ],
    "tax_reference" : [{
            "tax_number" : "The tax number of customer corresponding to the specific \"tax number type\" and country.",
            "tax_number_type_code" : "Defines the type of the corresponding tax number.",
            "iso_country_code" : "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.  "
        }
    ],
    "geo_location" : {
        "formatted_address" : "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
        "lat" : 55.6880806,
        "lng" : 12.5976728,
        "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
                "lat" : 55.6894295802915,
                "lng" : 12.5990217802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
                "lat" : 55.6867316197085,
                "lng" : 12.5963238197085
            }
        }
    },
    "customer_contacts" : [{
            "first_name" : "First name of the contact.",
            "last_name" : "Last name of the contact.",
            "int_sal_code" : "Local salutation, like San (in Japanese), Herr\n(in Deutsche) etc.",
            "primary_sal_code" : "Primary salutation, like Mr., Mrs. Etc.",
            "job_title" : "Job title of the contact in his/her\norganization.",
            "department" : "Department of the contact in his/her\norganization.",
            "email_address" : "Email address of the contact.",
            "contact_address" : {
                "street" : "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer contact",
                "house_number" : "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                "po_box" : "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                "building" : "Provides the building (if any) of the customer contact.",
                "district" : "Provides the district (if any) of the customer contact.",
                "city" : "City name corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                "postal_code" : "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                "iso_subdivision_code" : "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer contact.",
                "iso_country_code" : "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
                "geo_location" : {
                    "formatted_address" : "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
                    "lat" : 55.6880806,
                    "lng" : 12.5976728,
                    "viewport" : {
                        "northeast" : {
                            "lat" : 55.6894295802915,
                            "lng" : 12.5990217802915
                        },
                        "southwest" : {
                            "lat" : 55.6867316197085,
                            "lng" : 12.5963238197085
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "telecom" : [{
                    "type" : "Type of telecom device, phone, mobile, fax, etc. This may be a seleted from a list of suggestions",
                    "int_dial_code" : "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the telecom device.",
                    "phone_number" : "Defines the phone number of the device",
                    "extension" : "Extension of the device, if any."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When piping to stout i get:

```
Watching table customers.datamodel []
Logstash startup completed

{
            "db" => "customers",
         "table" => "datamodel",
       "old_val" => nil,
       "new_val" => {
                   "alternative_trading_name" => [
            [0] "Company alternative name or abberiviation, 1 of many.",
            [1] "Company alternative name or abberiviation, 2 of many."
        ],
                                   "building" => "Provides the building (if any) of the customer.",
                                       "city" => "City name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                          "customer_contacts" => [
            [0] {
                    "contact_address" => {
                                "building" => "Provides the building (if any) of the customer contact.",
                                    "city" => "City name corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                                "district" => "Provides the district (if any) of the customer contact.",
                            "geo_location" => {
                        "formatted_address" => "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
                                      "lat" => 55.6880806,
                                      "lng" => 12.5976728,
                                 "viewport" => {
                            "northeast" => {
                                "lat" => 55.6894295802915,
                                "lng" => 12.5990217802915
                            },
                            "southwest" => {
                                "lat" => 55.6867316197085,
                                "lng" => 12.5963238197085
                            }
                        }
                    },
                            "house_number" => "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                        "iso_country_code" => "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
                    "iso_subdivision_code" => "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer contact.",
                                  "po_box" => "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                             "postal_code" => "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
                                  "street" => "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer contact"
                },
                         "department" => "Department of the contact in his/her\norganization.",
                      "email_address" => "Email address of the contact.",
                         "first_name" => "First name of the contact.",
                "int_salutation_code" => "Primary salutation, like Mr., Mrs. Etc.",
                          "job_title" => "Job title of the contact in his/her\norganization.",
                          "last_name" => "Last name of the contact.",
                "loc_salutation_code" => "Local salutation, like San (in Japanese), Herr\n(in Deutsche) etc.",
                            "telecom" => [
                    [0] {
                                         "extension" => "Extension of the device, if any.",
                        "international_dialing_code" => "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the telecom device.",
                                      "phone_number" => "Defines the phone number of the device",
                                              "type" => "Type of telecom device, phone, mobile, fax, etc. This may be a seleted from a list of suggestions"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
                           "customer_numbers" => [
            [0] {
                 "cust_number_type" => "Type of the customer code. E.g. \"Customer Code\" or \"Customer Alternate Code\" SAP or SCV etc.",
                "cust_number_value" => "Customer code or Customer Number"
            }
        ],
                                   "district" => "Provides the district (if any) of the customer.",
        "external_customer_reference_numbers" => [
            [0] {
                 "reference_number_type" => "DoDAAC etc. Reference data from another collection.",
                "reference_number_value" => "User provided data"
            }
        ],
                               "geo_location" => {
            "formatted_address" => "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
                          "lat" => 55.6880806,
                          "lng" => 12.5976728,
                     "viewport" => {
                "northeast" => {
                    "lat" => 55.6894295802915,
                    "lng" => 12.5990217802915
                },
                "southwest" => {
                    "lat" => 55.6867316197085,
                    "lng" => 12.5963238197085
                }
            }
        },
                                  "hierarchy" => [
            [0] {
                           "concern_code" => "This is a code to combine several companies into the same group. This is reference data from another collection.",
                "related_customer_doc_id" => "This is the doc_ID of the releated customer.",
                      "relationship_type" => "Description of the relationship. This is reference data from another collection."
            }
        ],
                               "house_number" => "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                                         "id" => "b586c597-f043-4857-80ca-2236ca6e9a3d",
                          "internal_use_only" => {
               "customer_segments" => [
                [0] 12345
            ],
            "customer_status_code" => "Defines the status of the customer. e.g. -\n\"Active\", \"Suspended\" etc. This is reference data from another collection.",
                   "customer_type" => "This is the type of customer. e.g. -\n\"External\", \"Internal\" etc. This is reference data from another collection.",
              "status_reason_code" => "Specifies the reason corresponding to the status\n- mainly for \"Inactive\" and \"Suspended\" statuses. This is reference data from another collection."
        },
                 "international_dialing_code" => "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the customer.",
                           "iso_country_code" => "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
                       "iso_subdivision_code" => "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer.",
                               "phone_number" => "Defines the Phone Number of the customer.",
                                     "po_box" => "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                                "postal_code" => "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                                     "street" => "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
                              "tax_reference" => [
            [0] {
                    "iso_country_code" => "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.  ",
                          "tax_number" => "The tax number of customer corresponding to the specific \"tax number type\" and country.",
                "tax_number_type_code" => "Defines the type of the corresponding tax number."
            }
        ],
                               "trading_name" => "This is the trading name of the customer.",
                                        "url" => "Provides the URL (if any) of the customer."
    },
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-02-03T16:54:16.309Z"
}
```

In ES i get:

```
"hits": [
{
"_index": "newcustomer",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "AVKoFwPEnFxm1nt5POrY",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"db": "customers",
"table": "datamodel",
"old_val": null,
"new_val": {
"alternative_trading_name": [
"Company alternative name or abberiviation, 1 of many."
,
"Company alternative name or abberiviation, 2 of many."
],
"building": "Provides the building (if any) of the customer.",
"city": "City name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"customer_contacts": [
{
"contact_address": {
"building": "Provides the building (if any) of the customer contact.",
"city": "City name corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
"district": "Provides the district (if any) of the customer contact.",
"geo_location": {
"formatted_address": "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
"lat": 55.6880806,
"lng": 12.5976728,
"viewport": {
"northeast": {
"lat": 55.6894295802915,
"lng": 12.5990217802915
},
"southwest": {
"lat": 55.6867316197085,
"lng": 12.5963238197085
}
}
},
"house_number": "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
"iso_country_code": "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
"iso_subdivision_code": "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer contact.",
"po_box": "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"postal_code": "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer contact.",
"street": "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer contact"
},
"department": "Department of the contact in his/her organization.",
"email_address": "Email address of the contact.",
"first_name": "First name of the contact.",
"int_salutation_code": "Primary salutation, like Mr., Mrs. Etc.",
"job_title": "Job title of the contact in his/her organization.",
"last_name": "Last name of the contact.",
"loc_salutation_code": "Local salutation, like San (in Japanese), Herr (in Deutsche) etc.",
"telecom": [
{
"extension": "Extension of the device, if any.",
"international_dialing_code": "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the telecom device.",
"phone_number": "Defines the phone number of the device",
"type": "Type of telecom device, phone, mobile, fax, etc. This may be a seleted from a list of suggestions"
}
]
}
],
"customer_numbers": [
{
"cust_number_type": "Type of the customer code. E.g. "Customer Code" or "Customer Alternate Code" SAP or SCV etc.",
"cust_number_value": "Customer code or Customer Number"
}
],
"district": "Provides the district (if any) of the customer.",
"external_customer_reference_numbers": [
{
"reference_number_type": "DoDAAC etc. Reference data from another collection.",
"reference_number_value": "User provided data"
}
],
"geo_location": {
"formatted_address": "Formatted address, if any is provided by external address.",
"lat": 55.6880806,
"lng": 12.5976728,
"viewport": {
"northeast": {
"lat": 55.6894295802915,
"lng": 12.5990217802915
},
"southwest": {
"lat": 55.6867316197085,
"lng": 12.5963238197085
}
}
},
"hierarchy": [
{
"concern_code": "This is a code to combine several companies into the same group. This is reference data from another collection.",
"related_customer_doc_id": "This is the doc_ID of the releated customer.",
"relationship_type": "Description of the relationship. This is reference data from another collection."
}
],
"house_number": "House Number corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"id": "b586c597-f043-4857-80ca-2236ca6e9a3d",
"internal_use_only": {
"customer_segments": [
12345
],
"customer_status_code": "Defines the status of the customer. e.g. - "Active", "Suspended" etc. This is reference data from another collection.",
"customer_type": "This is the type of customer. e.g. - "External", "Internal" etc. This is reference data from another collection.",
"status_reason_code": "Specifies the reason corresponding to the status - mainly for "Inactive" and "Suspended" statuses. This is reference data from another collection."
},
"international_dialing_code": "Defines the International Dialing Code corresponding to the phone number of the customer.",
"iso_country_code": "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection.",
"iso_subdivision_code": "The subdivision ISO code for the customer. This can be state, region etc. depending on the customer.",
"phone_number": "Defines the Phone Number of the customer.",
"po_box": "PO Box (if any) corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"postal_code": "Postal code corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"street": "Street name corresponding to the address of the customer.",
"tax_reference": [
{
"iso_country_code": "ISO (alpha-2) code of the country for which is tax information is applicable. This is reference data from another collection. ",
"tax_number": "The tax number of customer corresponding to the specific "tax number type" and country.",
"tax_number_type_code": "Defines the type of the corresponding tax number."
}
],
"trading_name": "This is the trading name of the customer.",
"url": "Provides the URL (if any) of the customer."
},
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2016-02-03T17:03:45.339Z"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share 1) a sample document (after transformation) you're currently indexing and which exposes the issues you're mentioning; and 2) a document (or part thereof) in the form you'd l like it to be indexed. This way we can better understand what you get and what you'd like.

Comment: I've given the stout, and updated the logstash.conf to do so. Does this help?

Comment: @Stevns did you fix this issue ?

Comment: Sadly no, and as reThink is sadly dead, i'll start looking as CouchDB.